# Page elements stop being responsive

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, iframe

I am newbie to the Asp.net so please bear with me for this :)

I added a hyperlink html tag like this

```
<h2><a class="iframe2 cboxElement" id="frameEdit" onclick="return OpenEditPage()">(EDIT)</a></h2>
```

Here is the OpenEditPage() method

```
<script>
        function OpenEditPage()
        {
            var pid = document.getElementById("ProjId").value;
            var link = document.getElementById("frameEdit");
            link.setAttribute('href', "/Project_MainPageEdit.aspx?editpid=" + pid);
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

As soon as I click **EDIT** hyperlink, edit page is opened in `Iframe`. But when i close the edit page, I return back to **MainPage** but all the buttons and other elements on the page become unresponsive until I refresh the page.

What's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

I added following code inside the script and it worked like a charm

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
     $(".iframe2").colorbox({ onClosed: function () { window.location.reload(); } });
});
```